# Using Google endpoints in different modules of the same app

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm quite new to development with Google App engine and other Google services of the Cloud platform and I'd like to create an app with different modules (so they can have their own lifecycle) which use endpoints.

I'm struggling with api paths because I don't know how to route requests to the good module.

My directory tree is like that:

```
/myApp
  /module1
    __init__.py
    main.py
  /module2
    __init__.py
    main.py
  module1.yaml
  module2.yaml
  dispatch.yaml
```

module1.yaml

```
application: myapp
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
module: module1
version: 0
api_version: 1

handlers:
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/spi.
# Apps send requests to /_ah/api, but the endpoints service handles mapping
# those requests to /_ah/spi.
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: module1.main.api

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

module2.yaml

```
application: myapp
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
module: module2
version: 0
api_version: 1

handlers:
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/spi.
# Apps send requests to /_ah/api, but the endpoints service handles mapping
# those requests to /_ah/spi.
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: module2.main.api

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/_ah/spi/*"
    module: module1

  - url: "*/_ah/spi/.*"
    module: module2
```

So I'd like my endpoints to be called with the name of the corresponding module somewhere ('_ah/api/module1' or 'module1/_ah/api'). I don't know what to put in the different .yaml files. I don't even know if what I'm doing is right, or possible.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can host different endpoints on different modules (now called **services**); the way to correctly address them is as follows:

`https://<service-name>-dot-<your-project-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api`

Now, let's say you have—as per your description—**module1** and **module2**, each one hosting different endpoints. You will call **module1** APIs by hitting:

`https://module1-dot-<your-project-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api`

And in a similar fashion, **module2** APIs:

`https://module2-dot-<your-project-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api`

If you want to dig deeper into how this URL schema works (including versions, which are another important part of the equation here), go read [Addressing microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/designing-microservice-api#addressing_microservices) and the immediately following section [Using API versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/designing-microservice-api#using_api_versions)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I now struggle with a new problem, described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183193/unable-to-get-google-endpoints-working-over-multiple-services so I set this one as resolved

Comment: actually I'd still like to see how the .yaml files look. Especially for the app to work in both dev server and cloud.