# Unable to get Google endpoints working over multiple services

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Thanks to asamarin I've been able to figure out how to get different endpoints within the same google app engine (cf [Using Google endpoints in different modules of the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166540/using-google-endpoints-in-different-modules-of-the-same-app)).

But I can't make it work (at least with the dev server, I've not tried to pushed it to the cloud). I have two modules: module1 and module2, each of them running an independent api (using google endpoints so).
In each moduleX/main.py I have this code:

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import remote

# ... some code

@endpoints.api(name="moduleX", version='v0') # X being 1 or 2 obviously
class ModuleX(remote.Service):

# ... definition of the different methods

api = endpoints.api_server([ModuleX])
```

When I run dev_appserver.py with the two corresponding module yaml files, they start well (module1 on localhost:8080, module2 on localhost:8081).

Here comes the problem:

- localhost:8080/_ah/api/explore works well and I can see my module1 API with the different methods
- localhost:8081/_ah/api/explore takes looooong time then find the exact same API than for module1 except than when I click on it, it can't find the methods.

I've played a bit with Postman to see what's going on under the wood and found out that both calls to localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis and localhost:8081/_ah... return the same information with the `discoveryRestUrl` being localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/module1/v0/rest. Which is funny you'll admit.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it only the dev server that doesn't handle endpoints with multiple services ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: any link/git repo to an existing project using endpoints over multiple services would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Found any solutions?

Comment: nope, we had to reorganize our project :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue only exists with dev_appserver, as I had the same problem as you locally but it worked fine once deployed.

My app.yaml for my endpoint service looks like this:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1
service: <module-name>

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: my_script.api

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Once deployed, in order to hit my api I send requests to `https://<module-name>-dot-<project-name>.appspot.com/_ah/api`

So for the code you gave, the endpoint you would need to hit would be `https://<module-name>-dot-<project-name>.appspot.com/_ah/api/<moduleX>/v0/<method>`
Note that `<module-name>` is defined in app.yaml and `<moduleX>` and `<method>` would be declared in the python code in `my_script.api`.

In order to get this working locally on dev_appserver, I believe you need to run each endpoint module in its own instance of dev_appserver, as is noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232580/putting-a-cloud-endpoints-api-in-a-separate-app-engine-module#comment38865609_24232580). Admittedly I have not gotten this to work fully locally, as when I try to do this I get errors about my datastore being locked, but I believe fixing that issue should be possible as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578822/5310738).